# Using 1GB transparent hugepages in Linux

Tags: c, linux, huge-pages

I was wondering if there's any way to use the 1GB transparent hugepages in Linux without the need to recompile applications? 
I know that for using 2MB transparent hugepages, one only needs to do the following (I use SLES 12.3):

```
echo always > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
```

Comment: I don't see how this is a *programming* question, especially since an explicit objective is to avoid even recompiling.

Comment: I don't mind recompiling if you know the solution!

Comment: They wouldn't be *transparent* if you needed to rebuild your applications.

Comment: @TobySpeight I know that I can change the allocate method to use it in my code. Also, without recompiling the code, I know that it's possible to use 2MB TH, but I don't know any way to use 1GB TH without rebuilding my code.

Comment: So the question is, "*Can I use 1GB pages transparently?*", then?  Anyway, that's not a programming question - I recommend you ask instead at [unix.se] or perhaps [sf].